# POP3 protocol. Operations STAT and LIST

Tags: c#, tcpclient, pop3

I try to realize simple mail client. Now I can retriev messages:

```
            // create an instance of TcpClient
            TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient();
            // HOST NAME POP SERVER and gmail uses port number 995 for POP 
            tcpclient.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995);
            // This is Secure Stream // opened the connection between client and POP Server
            System.Net.Security.SslStream sslstream = new SslStream(tcpclient.GetStream());
            // authenticate as client  
            sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop.gmail.com");
            //bool flag = sslstream.IsAuthenticated;   // check flag
            // Asssigned the writer to stream 
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sslstream);
            // Assigned reader to stream
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sslstream);
            // refer POP rfc command, there very few around 6-9 command
            sw.WriteLine("USER my_mail@gmail.com");
            // sent to server
            sw.Flush();
            sw.WriteLine("PASS my_pass");
            sw.Flush();
            // this will retrive your first email
            sw.WriteLine("RETR 1");
            sw.Flush();

            string str = string.Empty;
            string strTemp = string.Empty;
            while ((strTemp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // find the . character in line
                if (strTemp == ".")
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (strTemp.IndexOf("-ERR") != -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                str += strTemp;
            }

            //str = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // close the connection
            sw.WriteLine("QUIT");
            sw.Flush();

            richTextBox2.Text = str;
```

But when I try to realize operations `STAT` and `LIST` my programm crashes. I think there is a problem in cycle of reading streams. For operation `STAT` I try to read until `"\r\n"` (`strTemp = "\r\n"`) and for operation `LIST` - `".\r\n"` respectively.

This is my code for `STAT`:

```
            // create an instance of TcpClient
            TcpClient tcpclient = new TcpClient();
            // HOST NAME POP SERVER and gmail uses port number 995 for POP 
            tcpclient.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995);
            // This is Secure Stream // opened the connection between client and POP Server
            System.Net.Security.SslStream sslstream = new SslStream(tcpclient.GetStream());
            // authenticate as client  
            sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop.gmail.com");
            //bool flag = sslstream.IsAuthenticated;   // check flag
            // Asssigned the writer to stream 
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sslstream);
            // Assigned reader to stream
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sslstream);
            // refer POP rfc command, there very few around 6-9 command
            sw.WriteLine("USER my_mail@gmail.com");
            // sent to server
            sw.Flush();
            sw.WriteLine("PASS my_pass");
            sw.Flush();
            // this will retrive your first email
            sw.WriteLine("STAT");
            sw.Flush();

            string str = string.Empty;
            string strTemp = string.Empty;
            while ((strTemp = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // find the . character in line
                if (strTemp == "\r\n")
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (strTemp.IndexOf("-ERR") != -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                str += strTemp;
            }

            //str = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // close the connection
            sw.WriteLine("QUIT");
            sw.Flush();

            richTextBox2.Text = str;
```

After I press the button my main window is not responding. Where is my mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: Any valid reason why you disregard existing libraries, e.g. [OpenPOP](http://hpop.sourceforge.net)?

Comment: What's the "crash" exception (since this is CLR, there isn't a GPF, is there)? What code did you add to cause it? There aren't many telepathists here, y'know.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, I edited my question. This is task for my lab, so I can't import libraries in my project. I did it accroding to specifications and can't get why it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your app is most likely hung on `ReadLine()`. Note that [`StreamReader.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamreader.readline) does not include the `\r\n`. So your check for `\r\n` will never hit, hence that break statement will never hit.

You may simply need to change it to `if (strTemp == "")`. If that doesn't do the trick, you'll have to step through in the debugger.

Also note that blocking calls like this are not a good idea in the UI thread. You really should offload this to a background worker.

Comment: Jon B, no, it doesn't help. I tried `if (strTemp == null)` too. Also I don't know why I can't clear stream `reader.DiscardBufferedData();` after sending my login and pass